# "Как ни странно" или "как не странно"?

Tags: не-или-ни

"Как ни странно" или "как не странно"? Правила на частицу "не/ни" или правила на "устойчивые выражения"?

Поспорили с молодым человеком. Как пишется фраза:

> Он бросил жену и детей, как н(и/е) странно, он был безответственный человек.

Я говорю, что тут частица "не", так как отрицание, в смысле что очевиден данный факт из биографии персонажа. А молодой человек считает, что там "ни".

Answer (score 3):

*Как ни странно* - нет отрицания, утверждается, что странно.
*Как ни странно, но он ушёл = странно, но он ушёл.*

Уступительный союз **как ни, где ни, когда ни** усиливает смысл, а не отрицает. Если это СПП с уступительным придаточным - частица ни усилительная.

Второе предложение, простите, не поняла, что-то Вы здесь накрутили.

```
   Он бросил жену и детей, как н(и/е) он был 
   безответственный человек.
```

Вы хотели сказать, что он бросил жену и детей, несмотря на то, что не был безответственным человеком? Тогда здесь **как ни** нежелательно.

Возможно сказать:

*Он всё-таки бросил жену и детей, каким бы  ответственным человеком ни был*

По смыслу больше подходит без НЕ/НИ:

Он бросил жену и детей, так как  был безответственный человек.

---

Увидела исправление в вопросе, теперь понятно содержание, но смысл всё равно затемнён, запятые создают впечатление равноправности предложений. Согласна с другими участниками форума,первую часть предложения следует отделить от остального предложения, а с помощью точки с запятой (или даже точки), тире или двоеточия - выбирать автору. Я бы выбрала или двоеточие, или тире, причинно-следственные связи здесь явно прослеживаются.

Он бросил жену и детей:(почему?) как ни странно, он оказался безответственным человеком.

Он бросил жену и детей -  как ни странно, он оказался безответственным человеком. Второе предложение заключает в себе вывод: бросил, из этого следует, что безответственный.

Возможны и остальные предложенные варианты, каждый сам расставляет акценты, но что не НЕ, а НИ - это ваш молодой человек прав. Частица усилительная.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим два варианта произошедшей истории.

**Вариант №1.**

> Он бросил жену и детей. Как ни странно, оказалось, что он безответственный
>   человек.

Вывод о безответственности следует из того, что он бросил семью. И утверждается, что это странно, то есть никто бы от него этого ранее не ожидал.

**Вариант №2.**

> Ничего удивительного, что он бросил жену и детей. Как не странно и то, что он безответственный человек.

Вот здесь всё наоборот. Можно было заранее предположить, чем закончится история, и частица **не** служит для отрицания: нет ничего странного, что он оказался безответственным человеком.

Вам с молодым человеком следует убедиться, что вы одинаково понимаете сюжет истории.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение требует правки. Как вариант, можно изменить пунктуацию:

**Он бросил жену и детей: как ни странно, он оказался безответственным человеком.**

[Двоеточие в БСП ставится](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185)

> если вторая часть указывает на причину того, что описано в первой части, например: В развитых странах средний класс решает исход выборов: он составляет большинство населения. В это предложение можно вставить союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО

Частица НИ — усилительная, нет отрицания, утверждается, что странно. Даже если считать "как ни странно" устойчивым  выражением, это никак не влияет на правило, по которому ставится НИ.

Дополнение. Вы пишете:

> отрицание, в смысле что очевиден данный факт из биографии персонажа.

Если это отрицание "не странно" (нам это не кажется странным), то какую роль может играть слово "как"? Усилительную (по примеру "Как мне не хочется вставать по утрам!")? Нет, здесь это не подходит. Сравнительную (это не странно так же, как не странно другое)? Такой вариант возможен, но тогда предложение нужно перестроить.  Как вариант:

**Не странно, что он бросил жену и детей, как не странно (и то), что он был безответственный человек.**

Повторюсь: в любом случае предложение в исходной форме неприемлемо, его нужно изменить, и тогда каждому читателю будет ясно, странно автору или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант редактирования:

**Он бросил жену и детей; как ни странно, он оказался безответственным человеком.**

По смыслу это наиболее подходящий вариант к подобной ситуации.

***Как ни странно*** ― **усилительная** частица НИ в устойчивом обороте, здесь **нет отрицания**.

Пояснение

1) *Он бросил жену и детей,  то есть он оказался безответственным человеком.*  Так выглядит очевидный вывод из биографии.

2) Теперь автор хочет высказать **свое отношение** к этому факту с помощью вводной конструкции.

***Как ни странно*** (= это очень странно) является вводным сочетанием, оно выражает **отношение** говорящего к событию (в нем используется **только частица НИ**).

В самом сочетании **нет отрицания**, усилительная частица НИ  употреблена в уступительной конструкции со значением: "хотя это странно, но это так".

**Другой вариант** предложения с тем же смыслом:

*Он бросил жену и детей; это очень странно, но он оказался безответственным человеком.*

Answer (score 0):

Синонимы паре не странно,  ни странно -  не удивительно, ни удивительно.  Рассмотрим предложение так: "Он бросил жену и детей, не удивительно, - он был безответственный человек." Второй вариант:"Он бросил жену и детей, как ни удивительно, но он был безответственный человек." В первом случае явное отрицание, но тогда союз "как" совершено не вписывается, во втором - отрицания нет, зато его необходимо создать союзом" но" в конце предложения. Тогда всё становится на свои места, а семантика выражена более чётко.